# Artifactory npm repository verify username and password

Tags: npm, artifactory

I have created a npm virtual repo in artifactory. And i can publish after i `npm login`.

But when i use `npm install` command, it will show 403 which means must `npm login` first.

So how to let artifactory not check the username & password for npm repository?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe off topic, but you may run npm install with JFrog CLI and it does all of the authentication for you.

This can be acheived in two steps:

1. [Configure Artifactory server](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Configuration): `jfrog rt c rt-server-1`
2. [Run npm install](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingNpmPackages): `jfrog rt npm-install [your-virtual-repo]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see some documents: artifactory always do the authentication. So maybe it's unable to avoid. So i add authentication in .npmrc file.